# Ecommerce - allow user to add products

Tags: php, html, opencart

I have just started using opencart, but I'm good with moderate php. In opencart, the only way to add products currently is through the admin panel. I would like to let users have the option of adding products, without seeing any of the admin panel, like ebay without the auction or amazon. I tried looking at the database to see how it is organized, but there are WAY too many tables. Also, I can't locate the php script that inserts the new product information into the database. Does anyone have an extension or at least know how opencart inserts the product in the database?

Thanks for all the help and sorry for the paragraph.

Comment: your best hope is that there is a module\plugin for this.

Comment: This question is opencart specific and should be asked on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you are looking for is `/admin/model/catalog/product.php`. You will see that there is a method called `addProduct` which you will have to replicate, remove anything that shouldn't be accessible and you'll also need to create the form for it too. For more info on the MVC, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478995/how-to-become-an-opencart-guru/13484904#13484904)